# Highcharts; disabling the tooltip for a single point renders a random little box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I have been utilising the react-highcharts wrappers for highcharts.

I am using the following snippet to disable the tooltip for a point in my series for a donut chart.

`...
tooltip: {
            formatter: function(){
                if (this.point.tooltipEnabled) {
                    return this.series.name;
                }
                return false;
            }
          },
...`

But when the formatter returns false the very first time it is called highcharts renders a random little box in the top left hand corner like this...

[image]

If I hover the blue one first it doesnt show the little box on subsequently hovering the grey though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug which appeared in Highcharts 5. Reported [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5922).

Use the latest development version:

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.src.js"></script>
```

or the previous version:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/4.2.7/highcharts.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p9mwgs18/3/

Comment: @morganfee Are you aware of a way to disable the highlight on hover by any chance?

Comment: For all series you can disable it via plotOptions.series.states.hover.enabled = false; http://jsfiddle.net/p9mwgs18/5/